# How to set to null the reference on a ForeignKey - Django

Tags: python, django

I've just started in Python and Django and I'm trying to do something pretty easy, but after many hours searching I haven't found the answer, so here it comes my question:

I have to Models: User (CustomUser) and House.

I want to have a field in User that references a House and that can be optional, emulating the fact that a person can be inside (when a reference is attached) or outside (when it's null) a house.
In the House model, I want to have also a "list" of people (Users) that are at a given moment inside the house.

To accomplish this, I've done something like this:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
 # other attrs ...

 # (ForeignKey) house: House where the user is right now
 house = models.ForeignKey(House,
  verbose_name='where is the user right now',
  related_name='house_now', blank=True, null=True,
  on_delete=models.SET_NULL
 )
 def leaveHouse(self):
    house = self.house.delete()

class House(models.Model):
 # (ManyToManyField) people: List of Users that are currently within the house
 people = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
           verbose_name='people inside the house right now',
           related_name='people',
           blank=True
        )

 def removeUser(self, user):
  self.people.remove(user)
```

The problem is that when I use the function leaveHouse of the User model, instead of setting the ForeignKey to Null or Empty, it deletes the House object referenced to the key.

Any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong, best practices and that kind of stuff please?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Anyway, just a little question related to this.
Why in the django admin if I set the field "house" as "----" (None) works fine, but if I set the field "home" as "----" gives me 
"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pk'"

```
# (ForeignKey) home: Main house
    home = models.ForeignKey(House,
        verbose_name='default house',
        related_name='home', blank=True, null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of deleting the related `house` object, set the link value to `None`:

```
self.house = None
self.save()
```

Comment: Oopss.. Thanks you! I had tried with setting it to None, but didn't know anything about save.

self.save() does save the state of the object then?

P.S: @alecxe Read the edit in the main question please :)

Comment: @GuillermoLópez okay, what if you would delete that `on_delete=models.SET_NULL` part? Does it make any difference? Thanks.

Comment: Figured it out >.<
Had a function in the same model that tried to access to that field and I didn't make the right checks for when is None. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old and already answered, but I'd like to point out that your model design is not the best for a number of reasons.

You shouldn't set the ManyToMany field in the House model, unless you want a User to be simultaneously in more than one house.

Using a foreign key to the House model when a ManyToMany relationship already exists is wrong as you could set a connection between a User and a House with the ManyToMany connection table and have a null value set for the Foreign Key.

Regarding the use the `related_name` parameter of the ManyToMany field, I think you understood it wrongly. That's the name you would use to access the houses list from the User model as `user.<related_name>`. So `houses` would have been a better choice. The same applies to the `related_name` of the ForeignKey field to the House model, you would use it to access the users list from a House instance `house.<related_name>`, in this case `people` would fit.

I link the documentation of the latest Django version, but this still applies also to older versions
https://docs.djangoproject.com/it/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Given this, when you use the `removeUser` method to remove a user from a house, you are not acting on the ForeignKey as that is another (redundant) relation in the database.